# testing unexported functions

Tags: erlang

I'd like to test some unexported functions using rebar and common_test. What is a clean and efficient way to do this?

My inclination would be to set a macro at compile/test time, and switch on/off export_all in the modules that way, depending on whether it's a production or test build. I want it to be easy--e.g., I don't want to edit a config file before switching from production to test and vice versa. However, I don't see a way to pass arguments to the erl compiler using rebar. Did I miss it?

I know eunit can test unexported functions easily, but I've already got my infrastructure for common_test working well and I don't want to change my workflow right now.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add `+export_all` to your `erlc` options when you build the modules for your test run. You can do this with `{erl_opts, [export_all]}.` in your `rebar.config` file. I don't think you can pass extra `erlc` arguments to rebar at runtime (e.g. you can't do `rebar compile +export_all`) though.

Comment: It would be nice if you could override any of the config file options on the command line, in the same way you can cascade configuration params with OTP's app config system. A shame. It's just another thing to do to have to go in and edit the rebar.config file to deploy. I either have to add a script to build my build system or have yet another checklist item. They add up.

Comment: Well, to be fair, rebar compile can do a lot more than just erlc invocation. It has compile options for a lot of other build artefacts too (asn1, yecc, erlydtl, ...) so passing erlc arguments to random other compilers probably wouldn't be helpful in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Just realised you used `common_test`. Please ignore this reply if it doesn't apply!

I have a slightly more advanced way of testing un-exported functions that has the benefit of not exporting them, thus keeping the production code as intact as possible (there might be faults that only occur if some functions are not exported, but is not detected during testing if all functions are exported).

This is how it works using Rebar and EUnit.

In your source file, add these lines:

```
-ifdef(TEST).
-include("yourmodule_tests.hrl").
-endif.
```

In your `test` folder, add a file called `yourmodule_tests.hrl` (in contrast to, for example, `yourmodule_tests.erl` in the normal case) and add the following contents:

```
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

some_test() ->
    ?assertEqual(ok, internal_function()).
```

Add the following configuration to `rebar.config` (if you already have `erl_opts`, just add the new tuple to that list):

```
{erl_opts, [{i, "test"}]}.
```

When you run `rebar eunit` Rebar will define the `TEST` environment variable and your code will be "test compiled". That is, including your tests into your module and the tests will be able to access internal functions.

If you use anything else than Rebar, just make sure you compile your code with `erlc -DTEST ...` when your compiling for tests.

Comment: Aren't the erl_opts used anytime you compile with rebar? Which means I'd have to remove that attribute when using rebar to compile for production?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional compile options that are used by rebar when compiling for eunit. As noted by archaelus, you need the `+export_all` option to `erlc`. Add the line

```
{eunit_compile_opts, [export_all]}.
```

to your `rebar.config` file. This is in mentioned in the [rebar.config.sample](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/rebar.config.sample) file.